# How to store large amount of data in a variable for a batch bypassing heap size exception

Tags: batch, map, formatting, global-variables, heapsizelimit

I am stuck with the following error:
*'Batchable instance is too big: ProductDiscountsFormatterBatch'*

I have a junction object called Account_Product_Discounts__c with the information of, for each account and product, its personal discount.

I have two classes that are batch classes. The first one is formatting the data in order to have all the data stored in a variable with the format Account - List of Account_Product_Discounts__c.
The second one is used to send, for each account (customer), an email with a pdf with all the information of the products and discounts. That's why I need to populate this first variable, because I do not want to be chunked into 200 records each time, I need to send the email for each customer and their N products.
I will attach an image for better understanding:
[image: Example of my particular case]
The problem there is that when there are a lot of records on this Map <Id, List<Account_Product_Discounts__c>>, salesforce throws the error posted in the beginning.

I know this is because of the heap size exception, which is 12MB in an async method, but it is not enough for us.

Can you recommend another way? Or how to get around this limitation? Maybe concatenating batches could work around it, but there is a limit to that too. I am hopeless, please help me!

Summary of my code here:

```
public with sharing class ProductDiscountsFormatterBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.RaisesPlatformEvents,Database.Stateful {


    private String query;
    private Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>> mAccDiscounts = new Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>>();


    /**
     * @description Constructor.
     * @param void
     * @return void
    **/
    public ProductDiscountsFormatterBatch() {
        
        query = 'SELECT Id,Staffel__c, Product__c,Account__r.Communications_Language__c, Account__r.SIBO_Invoice_e_mail_address__c, product__r.AFS_Code_Subfamily_Local__c , product__r.AFS_Product_Code_External_Id__c, product__r.AFS_Product_Description__c, Account__c, Discount_Value__c,Name '+
                'FROM Account_Product_Discount__C'+
                ' WHERE Product__r.AFS_Product_Family__C <> \'\'  '+
                'ORDER BY Account__c, product__r.AFS_Code_Subfamily_Local__c ';

        if(Test.isRunningTest()) query += ' LIMIT 200';
    }

    /**
     * @description start: Instance member to retain state across transactions.
     * @param BatchableContext bc 
     * @return Database.QueryLocator
    **/
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
 
    /**
     * @description execute:Logic to be executed in each batch.
     * @param BatchableContext bc 
     * @param scope -> List of objects to be treated
     * @return void
     **/
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope){
        
        List<Account_Product_Discount__C> lAccProdDisc = (List<Account_Product_Discount__C>)scope;
        Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>> mAccDiscountsExecute = new Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>>();
//I tried to create this new local variable but error throws anyways.
        mAccDiscountsExecute.putAll(mAccDiscounts);        
        mAccDiscounts = new Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>>(); 

        for( Account_Product_Discount__C accProdDisc : lAccProdDisc){

            Id accId = accProdDisc.Account__c;
            if(accId == null){
                continue;
            }
            if(!mAccDiscountsExecute.containsKey(accId)){
                mAccDiscountsExecute.put(accId, new List<Account_Product_Discount__C>{accProdDisc});
            }
            else{                
                List<Account_Product_Discount__C> lAccProdDiscForThisAccount = mAccDiscountsExecute.get(accId);                
                lAccProdDiscForThisAccount.add(accProdDisc);
                mAccDiscountsExecute.put(accId, lAccProdDiscForThisAccount);
            }
        }
        mAccDiscounts.putAll(mAccDiscountsExecute);
    }


    /**
     * @name finish
     * @description finish:Logic to be executed at the end of the process.
     * @param BatchableContext bc 
     * @return void
    **/
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) Id batchMedId = Database.executeBatch(new ProductDiscountsSenderBatch(mAccDiscounts), 2);
    }

}
```

For an obvious question: Yes, I need all the fields of the query in the next batch.
For the performance, is it better to store them in a Map<Id, List< CustomProductClass >> as this CustomProductClass is a custom class with these fields?

I also tried lowering the batch size, but as you can see in the next image, the batch continues to fail (and ends up in the failed batch iteration, not doing all the iterations needed):
[image]

For extra information, the second batch:

```
public with sharing class ProductDiscountsSenderBatch implements Database.Batchable<List<sObject>>,Database.RaisesPlatformEvents, Database.Stateful {

    // Variables to track the process
    private String query;

    Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>> mIdAccDiscounts;
    OrgWideEmailAddress orgWideEmailAdd;
    Map<String,String> attachmentMap;


    /**
     * @description Constructor.
     * @param mAccDiscounts: Map with the Accounts ID and a list of Account_Product_Discount__C
     * @return void
    **/
    public ProductDiscountsSenderBatch(Map<Id,List<Account_Product_Discount__C>> mAccDiscounts) {
        this.mIdAccDiscounts = mAccDiscounts;
        this.attachmentMap = new Map<String,String>();
        OrgWideEmailAddress[] orgsWideEmailAdd = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'sales@sibofluidra.nl'];
        if(orgsWideEmailAdd != null){
            orgWideEmailAdd = orgsWideEmailAdd[0];
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description start: Instance member to retain state across transactions.
     * @param BatchableContext bc
     * @return Iterable
    **/
    public Iterable<List<sObject>> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return new AccountProductDiscountIterable(mIdAccDiscounts);
    }
 
    /**
     * @description execute:Logic to be executed in each batch.
     * @param BatchableContext bc 
     * @param scope -> List of objects to be treated
     * @return void
     **/
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<List<sObject>> scope){
       
        List<List<Account_Product_Discount__C>> listListsAccProdDisc = (List<List<Account_Product_Discount__C>>)scope;
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        
        for(List<Account_Product_Discount__C> listForThisAccount : listListsAccProdDisc){
            ProductDiscountsSenderHelper pdsh = new ProductDiscountsSenderHelper();
            Map<String, ProductPropertiesWrapper> mPropertiesHierarchy = pdsh.prepareAndFormatDataForPDF(listForThisAccount);
            if(mPropertiesHierarchy.isEmpty()){
                continue;
            }
            ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator pdf = new ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator();
                   
            Account_Product_Discount__C aPD = listForThisAccount[0];
            Account acc = aPD.Account__r;
            String languageAccount = acc?.Communications_Language__c;
            String accountEmail = acc?.SIBO_Invoice_e_mail_address__c;
            
            if(!String.isBlank(accountEmail)){
                ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator.Language language;
                switch on languageAccount{
                    when 'nl' {
                        language = ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator.Language.DUTCH;
                    }
                    when 'fr' {
                        language = ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator.Language.FRENCH;
                    }
                    when 'de' {
                        language = ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator.Language.GERMAN;
                    }
                    when else {
                        language = ProductDiscountsPDFGenerator.Language.ENGLISH;
                    }
                }
                String messageBody ='';
                messageBody = pdf.generatePDF(language, mPropertiesHierarchy);
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = attachmentConstruction(messageBody,acc.Id);
            
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMessage = emailMessageConstruction(attachment,accountEmail);
                lEmail.add(emailMessage);
            }
        }
        String pAppName = 'ProductDiscountsSender';
        try{           
            sendEmails(lEmail);
            try{
                insertAttachments();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                
                String pTitle = 'ProductDiscountsSenderBatch|insertAttachments';
                String pExternalId = Log_Util.createExternalId('insertAttachments');
                Log_Util.logGenericMessage(pAppName, pTitle, pExternalId, 'getCause:'+e.getCause()+'| getMessage:'+e.getMessage() + ' | ' + e.getStackTraceString(), 'EXCEPTION');
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String pTitle = 'ProductDiscountsSenderBatch|sendEmails';
            String pExternalId = Log_Util.createExternalId('sendEmails');
            Log_Util.logGenericMessage(pAppName, pTitle, pExternalId, 'getCause:'+e.getCause()+'| getMessage:'+e.getMessage() + ' | ' + e.getStackTraceString(), 'EXCEPTION');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @name finish
     * @description finish:Logic to be executed at the end of the process.
     * @param BatchableContext bc 
     * @return void
    **/
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        
    }

    /**
     * @description Sends the emails to all accounts.
     * @param listEmails
     * @return void
     **/
    private void sendEmails(List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> listEmails ){
    
        String pAppName = 'ProductDiscountsSender';
        String pTitle = 'ProductDiscountsSenderBatch|sendEmails';
        String pExternalId = Log_Util.createExternalId('sendEmails');
        String pInfoCorr = 'Emails correctly sent to next addresses: ';
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            
            
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sER = Messaging.sendEmail(listEmails,false);
            Integer i = 0;
            List<String> emailSentCorrectly = new List<String>();
            for (Messaging.SendEmailResult mr : sER){
                if (mr.isSuccess()) {
                    emailSentCorrectly.add(listEmails[i]?.toaddresses[0]);
                }  else {
                    // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                    for(Messaging.SendEmailError err : mr.getErrors()) {
                        Log_Util.logMessage(pAppName, pTitle, pExternalId, 'getStatusCode:'+err.getStatusCode()+'| getMessage:'+err.getMessage() + ' | ' + err.getFields());
                    }
                }
                ++i;
            }
            String pMessage = pInfoCorr+String.join(emailSentCorrectly,',');
            Log_Util.logMessage(pAppName, pTitle, pExternalId, pMessage);            
        }
    }

    /**
     * @description Creates a instance of EmailFileAttachment
     * @param messageBody HTML with all information
     * @return attachment
    */
    private Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachmentConstruction(String messageBody, String accountId){
        if(String.isBlank(messageBody)) return null;
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
        attach.setFileName('Discount List '+Date.today().year());
        attach.setInline(true);
        attach.Body = Blob.toPDF(messageBody);
        if(!String.isBlank(accountId)) attachmentMap.put(accountId,messageBody);
        return attach;
    } 

    /**
     * @description Creates a instance of SingleEmailMessage
     * @param attachment
     * @param email where we will send the email.
     * @return SingleEmailMessage
    */
    private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailMessageConstruction(Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment, String email){
        
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setUseSignature(false);        
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailAdd.Id);
        mail.setToAddresses(new string[]{email});
        //TODO add some template for the email body?
        mail.setSubject('subject example');
        String body='<html><body>Emails example</body>  </html>';
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment}); 
        return mail;
    } 

    /**
     * @description Creates and insert instances of ContentVersion with the PDF sent
     * @return void
    */
    private void insertAttachments(){
        ContentVersion[] contentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();
        Date today = Date.today();
        String fileName = 'Discount List '+String.valueOf(today).removeEnd(' 00:00:00')+'.pdf';

        for (String idAccount : attachmentMap.keySet()) {
            
            String body = attachmentMap.get(idAccount);
            ContentVersion contentVersion = createContentVersion(fileName,body,idAccount);
            contentVersions.add(contentVersion);
        }
        insert contentVersions;
    } 

    /**
     * @description Creates a instance of ContentVersion
     * @param fileName
     * @param body
     * @return ContentVersion
    */
    private ContentVersion createContentVersion(String fileName, String body, String firstpublishLocationId){
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
        contentVersion.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S = Stored in Salesforce
        contentVersion.PathOnClient = fileName;
        contentVersion.Title = fileName;
        contentVersion.firstpublishLocationId = firstpublishLocationId;
        contentVersion.VersionData = Blob.toPDF(body);
        return contentVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to recommend anything, because you haven't presented the relevant code of your second batch (which seem to be afflicted with the same problem). Can't you not do without the `stateful`, pass a list of Accounts instead of Account_Product_Discount__c into the scope, do the query of Account_Product_Discount__c in the `execute` method (for specific Accounts) and pass the result of this directly to the process sending the emails, not using the `finish` method at all?

Comment: Hi @FelixvanHove,thanks for the reply!I edited my post to add the second batch, but there seems to be a problem with the first one because of the memory used with this mAccDiscounts variable (and this affects the second one)
I didn't do the first query on account because it depends on the AccProdDisc__c (there are accounts without products).Do you think it is better to query on ALL accounts and then call the sender per account? It is not a bad idea but I am worried about the batch limits(calling batches on execute)
Also I wanted to avoid sending emails one by one(there are limits also there)

Comment: Have you considered storing the formatted data in a field on the account?  You should also consider document generation products that can generate the PDFs and do the mass mailing, so you don't have to deal with the batch limitations.